# Pixel launcher keeps stopping, after updating SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-x86

After updating the SDK, I'm having this problem when I run the emulator:
Pixel launcher keeps stopping,

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Please help me and thank you very much
Note: I use android studio 2.3.3

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/63792618

Answer (score 5):

Actually, [anas darai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8081225/anas-darai)'s comment is the answer, but I'll expand it a bit.
The general workaround is the following:

1. **Delete** the AVD and the system image;
2. **Download** the system image;
3. **Create** a new AVD;
4. **Start** the Android Emulator;

   4.a. **Click** on the *More* button (those 3 horizontal dots) in the **Nav Controls** (the bar next to the emulator);

   [image: Click on the More button (those 3 horizontal dots) in the Nav Controls (the bar next to the emulator)]

   4.b. **Click** on *Settings*;

   [image: Click on Settings]

   4.c. **Select** from the *OpenGL ES renderer* dropdown the option ***ANGLE(D3D11)***;

   [image: Select from the OpenGL ES renderer dropdown the option: ANGLE(D3D11)]

   4.d. **Restart** the Android Emulator.

Steps 1 to 3 are optional in most of the cases.

If it still isn't working, you should check the following:

- does your CPU meet the requirements? solution: check out the Hardware requirements from [Installation Instructions for HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows);
- does HAXM have enough RAM and heap space so it can run the AVD? solution: reinstall HAXM and use at least the recommended settings;
- for slightly different solutions, check out [Pixel launcher keeps stopping](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63792618).

Comment: Link to CPU requirements is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I found that by running from the command line, I can control the options better. I had a lot of trouble with this issue. Turns out it is the angle opengles. Apparently it is for Windows systems. Why not put it on the original drop down.
Below my startavd.bat content. It also produces a cmd window with lots of detail.(applies to windows)
Of course replace the path to emulator with the relevant one on your pc.

```
        F:\android-studiov3\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\emulator\emulator -avd Pixel_C_API_26  -verbose -accel auto -engine auto  -gpu angle -netspeed full -netdelay none -sdcard C:\Users\Theo.Enermax\.android\avd\extSdcard.img
pause
exit
rem options for  -gpu: auto, host,swiftshader, angle , off
rem options for -engine: auto, classic ,qemu2. (classic=qemu1)
```